# ssl page showing as using resources from a non ssl page...but its not

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, ssl, https

Google chrome is showing that my page uses some resources that are from a non secure source. But its not. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening. I have gone through all the code to see if there is anything getting called from a non secure page but I was not able to find anything. I have also used the following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The url in question is https://app.emailsmsmarketing.com/. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: There is only login page, and chrome isn't reporting anything wrong with it. If the problem occurs after login, check your scripts (ie. jquery plugins) and CSS for any external references.

Comment: Can't reproduce on just the login page, green padlock for me in Chrome 7. There is a 404 reference to `/templates/v2/css/jquery.pnotify.default.css` though.

Comment: For some weird reason it has started working correctly again. Thanks for the help tho guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you don't have third-party inclusions, such as widgets from facebook, google analytics code, AddThis buttons etc. Some widgets can load something dynamically via HTTP. See my [similar question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13107/firefox-reports-https-page-to-contain-non-secure-elements) that will possibly help you to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using fiddler and found that it isn't using anything from a non secure page. Chrome is also now showing the green padlock. I'm not sure what was wrong but it's working now.